# Turn off laptop's fan in Windows 10

Tags: laptop, windows-10, fan

My Lenovo laptop used to turn off its fan in Windows 7, this would save a lot of energy and battery would last maybe about 2 times more.

After upgrading to Windows 10 however it never turns off.

I wonder how can I fix it and what is the reason of this problem.

I've tried using dust removal of Lenovo energy management software, it speeds up fan for a while and in Windows 7, I would have silent fans afterwards but it's useless in Windows 10.

**UPDATE**

It was an Intel Graphic's driver bug and it's fixed now, if you're having this issue you need to update your Windows.

Comment: The fan uses way less energy than the CPU so, if you really were having the laptop run twice as long with the fan switched off, it was because the CPU was put into a low-power mode which meant it didn't need th fan to cool it. So you might want to investigate the power-saving options that Windows 10 provides, rather than just looking for things to do with the fan.

Comment: Thanks for your replay David, yet battery saving was really that much! CPU usage is as always. Can you suggest any particular settings?

Comment: No idea, sorry -- I don't use Windows 10 or have a Lenovo.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe try this guy in advanced power settings? Windows 10 upgrade defaulted my power settings, and if you're on "high performance" IIRC it will be set to active.

[image: See this guy in advanced power settings]

Comment: Thanks Arthur, it's on `balanced` and cooling policy is on `passive` mode for battery.

Comment: I almost wonder if installing Win10 messed with your EFI partition. Try seeing if there's a relevant setting in the BIOS/UEFI, modern ones interact with the OS bootloaders in odd ways.

Comment: No, there wasn't anything there neither.

Comment: Try "maximum processor state" on battery, same menu. Vendor may have had it set to 50% or something similar.

Comment: No, it's on 5%, I've tried 0 too!

Comment: Arthur, you mean `minimum`, right? Maximum is at 100%.

Comment: Maximum, I'm wondering if the old windows had it set to 50% as many vendors do.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem using a Dell Latitude Core i7, after upgrading to Windows 10, the Fan was running continuously in high speed mode, very annoying, I just switched from Balance power option to Power Saver, Problem solved, the fan runs in low speed most of the time and only when processor is pushed to the limit it speeds up for short periods of time.